# how to add if statement in array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

the code below works fine, but i want to add some if statement but i can't get it working.

```php
    case "playerList":
        $array = array();
        foreach($commands->getPlayers() as $key => $row) {
            foreach($commands->getMutedOrNot() as $key1 => $row1) {
            array_push($array, array(
                "<a href=\"player.php?player=".$key."\">".$key."</a>",
                $row,
                "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?ban=".$key."\">Ban</a>",
                "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?kick=".$key."\">Kick</a>",
                "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?mute=".$key."\">Mute</a>,
                "<a class=\"btn btn-success\" href=\"player.php?player=".$key."\">More Options</a>"
                ));
            }
        }

        $array = json_encode(array("data" => $array));
        print_r($array);
        break;
```

what i try to do is:

```
    case "playerList":
        $array = array();
        foreach($commands->getPlayers() as $key => $row) {
            foreach($commands->getMutedOrNot() as $key1 => $row1) {
            array_push($array, array(
                "<a href=\"player.php?player=".$key."\">".$key."</a>",
                $row,
                "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?ban=".$key."\">Ban</a>",
                "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?kick=".$key."\">Kick</a>",
                if ($row1 == 1) {
                "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?mute=".$key."\">Mute</a>,
                } else {
                "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?unmute=".$key."\">Unmute</a>,
                }
                "<a class=\"btn btn-success\" href=\"player.php?player=".$key."\">More Options</a>"
                ));
            }
        }

        $array = json_encode(array("data" => $array));
        print_r($array);
        break;
```

can anyone tell me how to do it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional (aka ternary) expression.

```
array_push($array, array(
    "<a href=\"player.php?player=".$key."\">".$key."</a>",
    $row,
    "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?ban=".$key."\">Ban</a>",
    "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?kick=".$key."\">Kick</a>",
    $row1 == 1 ?
        "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?mute=".$key."\">Mute</a>"
        :
        "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"?unmute=".$key."\">Unmute</a>",
    "<a class=\"btn btn-success\" href=\"player.php?player=".$key."\">More Options</a>"
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
( $row1 == 1 ? "<a class='btn btn-primary' href='?mute={$key}'>Mute</a>" : "<a class='btn btn-primary' href='?unmute=$key'>Unmute</a>" )
```

You can use a ternary operator `?` to perform conditional expressions in a statement. This shorthand means `if $row1 == 1` then return `"<a class='btn btn-primary' href='?mute={$key}'>Mute</a>"`, else return `"<a class='btn btn-primary' href='?unmute={$key}'>Unmute</a>"`